# In what sense is random variable a relabeling of the points in the sample space

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

I was inspired by [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wHvvTzyRlB4) to think more deeply about random variables. I'm grouping several question about them together, because I think they are interconnected.

### What I (think I) know

I've gathered from Wikipedia that a random variable $X$ is a measurable function $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P) \to (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ [1].

I understand from its properties that whatever is measurable in the reals, has to be measurable over in the $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ as well — i.e. it must have some associated probability. That means that for any measurable set $S$ we can write

$$\mathrm{P}(X \in S)=\mathrm{P}(\{\omega \in \Omega \mid X(\omega) \in S\}),$$

and be sure that $P$ is defined on such set.

### Where I struggle

1. The speaker in the video says that random variables are basically a way to rename the points in $\Omega$ while preserving the "structure" of the whole probability space. So, my first question is: **is that so?**
2. Now, I don't fully intuitively grasp **what the structure of the probability space is, and how it is preserved**. The random variable guarantees not to add any new measurable sets, sure, but as fair as I understand it, it doesn't promise not to drop any — and I would've thought that would constitute a change of structure. And even if it didn't (e.g. by definition), it feels weird to call this "renaming".
3. (bonus) Did we choose measurable functions for random variables only because it's nice to be able to safely ask about the value of $P(X \leq 10)$, or is there more to it?

So, if the random variable *isn't* a simple renaming, how can I intuitively understand it? (an understanding of type "a structure-preserving function into reals, because they are easier to work with" is ok, provided I understand what the "structure" means in this context).

[1]: I don't understand Lebesgue measure nor $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ very much, but I take it as a given that it's the "intuitive" $\sigma$-algebra over reals.

Comment: Can someone please say the thing I don't want to say to him?

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen Could you be more specific, please?

Comment: You see. This video annoys me. And if he said something about "rename" , then God, please! How misleading.  I don't want to comment too much on this topic as I'm not a fan of vulgarisation (even though I have to do it when teaching). Vulgarisation of concept won't get any serious researcher go anywhere in his direction.

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen Interesting. For me, it struct a nice balance between the "common" [simplified way of explaining RVs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1411825/definition-of-random-variable-on-measure-theory?rq=1) and the measure-theoretic one. And I, for one, don't see anything particularly bad about the word "relabeling" — isomorphic linear mappings can be described in this way as well, and I don't find it to contradict the underlaying mathematical principles.

Comment: The nature of isomorphism can be described as "relabeling" but that kind of saying is just misleading with random variables.  Not about the balance.

Comment: If you think it does not contradict anything then you can just go with it. I won't argue more.

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen Didn't mean to offend. I was trying to say that "relabel" _does_ apply _sometimes_, and that I liked the video as a whole. However, I myself was wondering whether it applies in the case of random variables as well, hence this whole questions.